# How to manage android devices using without emm console

Tags: enterprise, mdm, emm

I have generated a Qr code for provisioning or enrolling android devices using android management api. But how to manage these devices without purchasing licence from third party emm console. Idls there any way to manage these enrolled devices

Please share the solution of my problem